# Trigonometric proof? Product to Sum.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble with proving these:

$$\sin^2(70^\circ)\sin^2(50^\circ)\sin^2(10^\circ)=\frac{1}{64}$$
$$16\sin(10^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)\sin(70^\circ)\sin(90^\circ)=1$$

I don't know, but I think we have to use

$$\cos(140^\circ)=-\sin(50^\circ).$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

As $\sin(3\cdot10^\circ)=\dfrac12,$

$\sin(3\cdot50^\circ)=\sin(180^\circ-30^\circ)=\cdots=\dfrac12,$

and $\sin(3\cdot70^\circ)=\sin(180^\circ+30^\circ)=\cdots=-\dfrac12,$

So, $\sin10^\circ,\sin50^\circ,\sin(-70^\circ)=-\sin70^\circ$ are the roots of $$3\sin x-4\sin^3x=\dfrac12\iff4\sin^3x-3\sin x+\dfrac12=0$$

Using Vieta's formula,

$$\sin10^\circ\cdot\sin50^\circ\cdot(-\sin70^\circ)=-\dfrac{\dfrac12}4$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\sin (60^\circ-A)\cdot \sin (A)\cdot \sin (60^\circ+A) = \frac{1}{4}\sin (3A)$$

$\bf{Proof::}$ Given $\displaystyle \sin (60^\circ-A)\cdot \sin (A)\cdot \sin (60^\circ+A) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\sin (60^\circ+A)\cdot \sin (60^\circ-A)\right]\sin A$

Now Using $2\sin A\sin B = \cos(A-B)-\cos (A+B)$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos (2A)- \cos(120^\circ)\right]\sin A = \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos (2A)+\frac{1}{2}\right]\sin A$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\cos (2A)\sin A+\frac{1}{4}\sin A = \frac{1}{4}\left[2\cos (2A)\sin A\right]+\frac{1}{4}\sin A = \frac{1}{4}\sin (3A)-\frac{1}{4}\sin A-\frac{1}{4}\sin A$

So we get $\displaystyle   \sin (60^\circ-A)\cdot \sin (A)\cdot \sin (60^\circ+A) = \frac{1}{4}\sin 3A$

For $\bf{1^{st}}$ one:: Put $A=10^\circ\;,$ We get $\displaystyle \sin(50^\circ)\cdot \sin(10^\circ)\cdot \sin (70^\circ) = \frac{1}{4}\sin (30^\circ)$

Answer (score 1):

Using $\sin(90^\circ-A)=\cos A,$

$$F=\sin70^\circ\sin50^\circ\sin10^\circ=\cos20^\circ\cos40^\circ\cos80^\circ$$

Using $\sin2C=2\sin C\cos C,$

$$F=\dfrac{2\sin20^\circ\cos20^\circ}{2\sin20^\circ}\cdot\cos40^\circ\cos80^\circ$$

$$=\dfrac{2\sin40^\circ\cos40^\circ}{4\sin20^\circ}\cos80^\circ$$

$$=\dfrac{2\sin80^\circ\cos80^\circ}{8\sin20^\circ}$$

$$=\dfrac18$$ using $\sin(180^\circ-B)=\sin B$

Comment: Simple as it should be.+1

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sin^2 (70^\circ)\sin^2 (50^\circ)\sin^2 (10^\circ) = \frac{\sin^2 (10^\circ)\sin^2 (20^\circ)\sin^2 (30^\circ)\sin^2 (40^\circ)\sin^2 (50^\circ)\sin^2 (60^\circ)\sin^2 (70^\circ)\sin^2 (80^\circ)}{\bigg[\sin^2(30^\circ)\bigg]\bigg[\sin^2 (20^\circ)\sin^2 (40^\circ)\sin^2 (60^\circ)\sin^2 (80^\circ)\bigg]}$$